# Within a product loop, get posts associated with custom taxonomy terms and current product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I'm working with WooCommerce in Wordpress. I've got three products (called "Kits") and each kit contains several items. The "items" are a custom post type which are linked to each kit via a relationship field. Each item has a custom taxonomy attached to it ("departments"). 
The departments have no direct link to the products (or "kits"), except via the items.

When I display the products, I want them to show a `<ul>` that loops through each term found in department. Then within that `<li>`, have a nested `<ul>` that lists each item that is found in the current department AND in the current product.

I've got a loop that's working to display the items associated with each product:

```
<a href="#details<?php the_ID(); ?>" class="details button" data-id = "<?php the_ID() ?>">Details</a>
<div class="items" id="details<?php the_ID(); ?>">  
    <?php  $items = get_field('kit_items');?>
    <?php if( $items ): ?>
        <ul>
        <?php foreach( $items as $item ): ?>
            <?php $ident = $item->ID ?>
            <li>
                <a href="#overlay<?php echo $ident ?>" class="item item<?php echo $ident ?>" data-id ="<?php echo $ident ?>">
                    <?php echo get_the_title( $item->ID ); ?>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        </ul>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

But I'm not sure how to query the custom taxonomy, print out the terms and then print the items that are associated with the department and the current product.